# Qt application shows emoji instead of unicode character

Tags: macos, qt, unicode, qml, emoji

I am currently developing an application with Qt. I'm using macOS Sierra as my development and testing environment, but the application is cross-platform.

So here's the issue. I am creating a Qt Quick `Text` item where I set the following property `text: "\u2139"`, in order to show the [information icon](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2139/index.htm). The font family I'm using is [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open%20Sans).

Upon running the application, I was surprised to see the following on the place where my unicode character should come:

[image: emoji information symbol]

That's not what I wanted, I wanted the text presentation of that unicode character, not the emoji presentation. How can I force the text presentation to be shown (on all platforms)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you misinterpret what unicode emojis are. An emoji is a text character and is rendered using a font as any other character. So you have what you asked for. Now depending on your OS, there may be different font policies for emojis so you may or may not have result changing the font from your Qt program. you may need to tweak the system.

Comment: So this is a font-specific issue you think?

Comment: Yes it is. `\u2139` is rendered using a font. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214401/where-are-emojis-stored-on-macs

Comment: Is there a way to exclude that font from being used in my application?

Comment: It doesn't matter what font you select, macOS translates the unicode character to an emoji regardless. I'd also appreciate a real answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation) you should follow that character by the U+EF0E {VARIATION SELECTOR 15} which requests the rending system to present the preceding glyph in a textual (mono-chrome) form; to do the opposite i.e. to request the Emoji (colourful) representation you should follow it by the U+EF0F {VARIATION SELECTOR 16} code-point instead.  Particularly for the latter, whether you can get the colourful form is highly system/display widget selective and it is not obvious which code-points render in which way if not specified.  For instance these three glyphs:

︎️ without a variation selector
︎︎︎️︎ each followed by VS15
️︎️️️ each followed by VS16

**Aaarg! They totally fail to show up differently on Stack Exchange**
*grrrr!*

However saving this as an html file using HTML entities and opening it in my browser:

```
<html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><head/>
<body><p>&#128528;&#128542;&#128512; without a variation selector</p>
<p>&#128528;&#65038;&#128542;&#65038;&#128512;&#65038; each followed by VS15</p>
<p>&#128528;&#65039;&#128542;&#65039;&#128512;&#65039; each followed by VS16</p>
</body></html>
```

it only seems to produce the Emoji effect when told to:

[image: Partial screen shot of above HTML display in my Browser]

From my own recent work on a project using Qt C++ widgets it seems that most (all I have tried) of them do not handle the Emoji form - though I haven't tried `QTextBrowser` which would seem to be the most likely one to handle those - it just would not be applicable to what I am doing...

Also the Emoji form for the 102 human like Emojis can also be combined with a further five U+1F3FB to U+1F3FF {EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-xxxx} (*the first one is for types 1 AND 2, the rest are for 3 to 6 respectively*) which give a realistic and increasingly darker skin tone to them.  Note that the default yellow/blue/grey base colour for the baseline human emojis is expressly those colours to **not** be human-skin-tone-like!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `font-family: Helvetica, Arial;` will override the OS's emoji default.